# How integrate .ICS file to Google Calendar directly OR How can I subscribe to google calendar from the app?

Tags: android, calendar, google-calendar-api, icalendar

I have an android app where I want to give the user an option to toggle on and off calendar sync.
Using the below lines of code it is opening a browser and then downloading the .ics file and then trying to open it in the calendar in a browser. Instead, I want it to directly open the calendar app and import the events. "http://mylink" this link is the link to the .ics file

```
   String url = "http://www.google.com/calendar/render?cid=http://mylink";
   Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
   startActivity(intent);
```